# How to Define Custom Traits on Grapes-js and How to Change the DomComponents as per traits values

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

How to Define Custom Traits on Grapes-js and How to Change the Dom-Components as per traits values.
I am trying to do changing the position of the components by selecting the option on traits like if I Select traits to top-right the component should be moved to top-right.

```
editor.DomComponents.addType('div', {
    isComponent: el => el.tagName == 'DIV',
    model: {
      defaults: {
        traits: [
          // Strings are automatically converted to text types
          {
            type: 'select', // Type of the trait
            label: 'Type', // The label you will see in Settings
            name: 'type', // The name of the attribute/property to use on component
            options: [
              { id: 'top-center', name: 'TopCenter'},
              { id: 'top-right', name: 'TopRight'},
              { id: 'top-left', name: 'TopLeft'},
              { id: 'center', name: 'Center'},
              { id: 'center-left', name: 'CenterLeft'},
              { id: 'center-right', name: 'CenterRight'},
              { id: 'bottom-center', name: 'BottomCenter'},
              { id: 'bottom-right', name: 'BottomRight'},
              { id: 'bottom-left', name: 'BottomLeft'},
            ]
          }
          
        ],
       
        // As by default, traits are binded to attributes, so to define
        // their initial value we can use attributes
      },

      init() {
        this.on('change:attributes:type', this.handleTypeChange);
      },
  
      handleTypeChange() {
        console.log('Input type changed to: ', this.getAttributes().type);
      },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As from [documentation](https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/Components.html#lifecycle-hooks) on `init` stage html is not rendered yet, you can use `updated` local hook instead. Here is an example of what you can do:

```
editor.DomComponents.addType('div', {
    isComponent: el => el.tagName == 'DIV',
    model: {
      defaults: {
         // your traits
      },
        updated(property, value, prevValue) {
            // only if traits are updated
            if(property === 'traits') {
                const el = this.view.el; // target your div 
                const traits = this.getTraits();
                applyTraits(el, traits);
            }
        },
    },
});
```

And in `applyTraits` function you can apply corresponding CSS:

```
cosnt applyTraits = (el, traits) => {

if(traits.find(trait => trait.attributes.name === "TopCenter").attributes.value){
   el.style.top = 0;
   el.style.left = '50%';
}

// ... your logic

}
```

Note that it's just a brief example of what you can do. In `applyTraits` you can use arrays, or maybe split your traits to horizontal and vertical axis so you will have to set 2 traits to apply position TopCenter e.g. name: 'top' for y, name: 'center' for x